# FOSUserBundle and Symfony 3.0?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

Does FOSUserBundle work with symfony 3? Can't see any info regarding that on their site.

I have just installed a fresh copy of Symfony 3, did `composer update`, and then did tried to install FOSUserBundle.

Receiving something not very friendly on the console ;)

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/security-bundle 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.1 requires symfony/security-bundle >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.2 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11,
v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6,
v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.3 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11,
v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6,
v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.4 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11,
v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6,
v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.5 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11,
v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6,
v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.6 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11,
v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6,
v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6].
```

Comment: Nope. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1996.  Even though FOSUserBundle is by far the most used bundle it basically is not being kept up to date in any useful fashion.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: In the citated comment talk about compatibility: **in the  the master branch is now compatible with Symfony** can you try with  `"dev-master"` version

Comment: `dev-master@dev` worked! Didn't test it very thoroughly but so far it's not throwing any errors. Thanks @Matteo

Comment: Hi @Karolis I post the comment as an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a tagged version (official version) for support of the new framework version, BTW, in [this github issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1996) says that:

> in the the master branch is now compatible with Symfony.

So try with this composer configuration

```
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle: "dev-master"
```

Hope this help

Comment: Just keep in mind that you probably were not using the master branch in your existing app.  You were probably using an earlier version which is incompatible with the unreleased master branch.  So even though it loads it probably does not work.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad! Of course! Is only a temporary solutions. I will update my answer when will release a stable version for it

Comment: My point is that existing apps use V1.3.  The development branch is 2.0.  2.0 has never been released (except in alpha) and is very different than 1.3.  So existing apps which switch to the development branch probably won't work.  And even if they did then the app would be dependent on unstable code.  Code which has been worked on for 3+ years without ever being released.  And no target release date in sight.

Comment: Hi @Cerad thanks for this info! I don't knew it! Really dangerous so!

Answer (score 6):

This command worked for me with Symfony 3.2.1:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing my composer.json to include

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0.0"
```

and then running

```
composer update
```

worked for me after finding this [packagist page](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle)

The end result (of installing the bundle) is the same and in my opinion, the requirement statement looks/feels better in my project by not being a dev branch.