# Troubles installing FOSUserBundle in Symfony 3.0.4

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

I get this error when installing FOSUserBundle on Symfony3.

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
  The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle".
Here is my security.yml

```
security:

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    #dev:
    #    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    #    security: false

    main:
        anonymous: true
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/chat, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I think this bundle is not ready for Symfony3. Citing the docs "The FOSUserBundle adds support for a database-backed user system in Symfony2"

Comment: means not possible to use this bundle for now?

Comment: That would be it. Is it still time for you to set up a Symfony2 project? Latest versions have all the functionalities offered by Symfony 3.0, meaning you would loose only what is new from 3.0 to 3.0.4.

Comment: Oh, but look at that ! Seems there is a workaround...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320624/fosuserbundle-and-symfony-3-0?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `providers` keys in your `security.yml` file which means that the second one is never loaded (as specified by the YAML specs). Thus, your application doesn't know anything about the FOSUserBundle user provider, but only knows your in-memory user provider.